# Create Dynamic Rege in Runtime

Tags: javascript, dynamic, replace

Friends its possible to create javascript dynamic regex at runtime. i create this regex:

```
[+]?\(?800\)?[+ .]?123?[+ .]?1234
```

for this 800.123.1234 number. This regex can found/accept this number on page in any format
like:

```
(800).123.1234
+(800)1231234
+(800)1231234
(800).123.1234
800.123.1234
800.123.1234
```

Its work fine but i need to create rejex dynamic depends on any number that i feed in input text field. here is my working code example:
http://jsfiddle.net/webdesignerart/ShbMv/

means if two numbers i have on page
800.123.1234 and 855.455.4577
i add this 855.455.4577 number to input text field
then regex have to create dynamic or parse

```
[+]?\(?800\)?[+ .]?123?[+ .]?1234
```

in this regex to find this 855.455.4577.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own regular expression object anytime using the `new RegExp(str)` syntax.

```
var str = "[+]?\\(?800\\)?[+ .]?123?[+ .]?1234";
var re = new RegExp(str);
re.exec("800.123.1234");
```

Note, you may need double backslashes on some declarations in order to allow a single backslash to survive into the regular expression constructor.

But, if I really understood what you were doing, there is probably a single regular expression that can be created in advance that will match what you need to match.   For example, you could match all the phone numbers you have in your list with this:

```
\+?\(?\d\d\d\)?\.?\d\d\d\.?\d\d\d\d

zero or one plus sign
zero or one left paren
3 digits
zero or one right paren
zero or one period
three digits
zero or one period
four digits
```

Here's a jsFiddle that tests all your test numbers against a regular expression and extracts just the numbers out of each form to make a normalize phone number form: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/43mqV/.  It uses this regular expression:

```
\+?\(?(\d\d\d)\)?\.?(\d\d\d)\.?(\d\d\d\d)
```

This is the same as above, but it also captures each group of numbers so we can pick out just the numbers from the matched results.

Comment: Can't clear to me:
var str = "[+]?\(?800\)?[+ .]?123?[+ .]?1234";
how i add number and create its rejex. can't clear.

Comment: Thanks i understand, this rejex accepts any numbers like this:
800.524.1358
800.258.1479
555.145.1234

i want my rejext accept those number that i add in input field
not all of numbers:
http://jsfiddle.net/webdesignerart/ShbMv/1/

Comment: @user836670 - Sorry, but I don't understand what your question is.  Also, please change your user ID to an actual name so we will recognize each other when our paths cross again.

Comment: Jfriend this \+?\(?(\d\d\d)\)?\.?(\d\d\d)\.?(\d\d\d\d)
 rejex accepts any numbers like this: 800.524.1358 800.258.1479 555.145.1234 i want my rejext accept those number that i add in input field not all of numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/webdesignerart/ShbMv/1/

Comment: I don't personally think I'd make a giant regex of all valid numbers.  It makes more sense to use a regex to parse the test number into it's pieces and then compare those normalized pieces to your list of valid numbers in a loop.

Comment: no no ok can we split number in and assign to variables and concatenate variable in rejex?

Answer (score 0):

Use \d where for the digits that can be any of 0 - 9.

Comment: thankx for your reply but i need my rejex dynamic:
http://jsfiddle.net/webdesignerart/ShbMv/1/
Now my form works with 800.123.1234 number and find/replace that number on page but if add this number: 866.135.1245 my rejex have to find this number on page so how to parse number in my rejex.